# Debugging VS Code with Typescript shows transpiled variable names instead of real names

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm struggling to find the right configuration such that VS Code will show me the real variable name for debugging.

[image: VS Code screenshot]

In the attached image, I should be able to see the `conn` (for example) variable but the debugger is showing the transpiled version `exports.conn`.

```
//tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "target":"es6",
        "module":"commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
        "esModuleInterop": false,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "web/**/*",
        "logger/**/*",
        "controller/**/*",
        "config/**/*",
        "**/*.ts"

    ]
}
```

```
// VS Code launch.json
      ...
               {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.ts",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*"]
        }
```

UPDATE: I'm not convinced this is a VS Code problem.  If I run the app from a terminal with `node dist/app` and get a stack trace it doesn't point back to the original TS files but rather the compiled JS files.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at new Config (/Users/zzz/Documents/programming/dist/config/Config.js:10:56)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zzz/Documents/programming/dist/config/Config.js:43:18)
```

UPDATE 2:
I fixed the CLI problem by moving `require('source-map-support').install();` to be my very first import.  Now the CLI output does show the correct line/stack trace back through the the .ts files but the same problem still exists in VS Code.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but have you tried [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging)?

Comment: I've been through that help page, but not sure what exactly you are referring to.  I do have sourceMap and outFiles specified.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure why, the code blocks & the image you've provided aren't loading my end, I'll take another look later if you've not had an answer before then.

Comment: Looks like it's not implemented feature of typescript source maps
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9627

Comment: Had a similar problem. Adding `"target": "es2016"` to the compilerOptions in my tsconfig.json solved it. Typescript generated less "obfuscated" js - files through this config. I know that this might not be a sufficient solution for this problem. But it might help some of the people reading this.