# typescript compiler source map emit names

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

[referencing this stack overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669155/debugging-vs-code-with-typescript-shows-transpiled-variable-names-instead-of-rea)

[referencing this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9627)

is it possible to instruct typescript to emit `names` on the source map?

One usage will be to debug `exports` values,
but i'm looking for a more general solution.

source code:

```
let a = 0;
```

emitted code:

```
ctx.a = 0;
```

debugger:

show the value of `ctx.a` instead of `a` as `a` does not exists anymore on the js context.