# Source maps using transpiled variable name

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, source-maps

After looking at a myriad of questions & answers:

- [Debug Angular/Typescript in visual code appends '_1' to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078164/debug-angular-typescript-in-visual-code-appends-1-to-variable?rq=4)
- [Debugging VS Code with Typescript shows transpiled variable names instead of real names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669155/debugging-vs-code-with-typescript-shows-transpiled-variable-names-instead-of-rea)
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131690

As well as videos describing debugging TS in VSCode:

- https://youtu.be/4zdBk6wisxc

I still cannot find my answer. The breakpoints hit when I debug my program but the only local variable names I can access are the transpiled ones & not the originals.

[image]

The screenshot above shows the app.ts with a breakpoint on it as well as the transpiled app.js & the local variables available to me in debugging. As you can see, I would expect the variable `cluster` to be visible but I only have `cluster_1` which I can access the `default` of but doesn't have the direct properties of `isPrimary` or `isWorker` *(cluster module)*.

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["src/**/*", "lib/**/*"]
}
```

**launch.json** *(configuration)*

```json
{
    "name": "Launch Scalper",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/scalper",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/scalper/dist/src/app.js",
    "request": "launch",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
    "type": "node",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy"
    ],
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/scalper/dist/**/*.js"
    ],
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Node version: **18.18.2** 
Typescript version: **5.5.3** 
VSCode version: **1.85.0**

I've been searching for hours & am really at a loss. I even looked at [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12066) but there doesn't seem to be a resolution apart from workarounds with webpack.

**EDIT:**

I've tried with `ts-node` so my configuration is now:

```json
{
    "name": "Launch Scalper",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/scalper",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/scalper/src/app.ts",
    "request": "launch",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
    "type": "node",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy",
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register"
    ],
    "sourceMaps": true,
}
```

I get the same where the breakpoint is still hit but the original variable name is not seen. Is this now a problem with the VSCode version?

Comment: linked GH issue ticket links to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9627.